# Insert data to column of excel to another excel column by matching it from a data of column using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have this problem to match and insert data from excel to another excel.
For example. I'll give an example to understand it.

This is the first excel that I'll insert the data

```
svc_no      MDF     aline  Result
27544381    DUMMY   DUMMY
27927915    DUMMY   DUMMY
29587987    DUMMY   DUMMY
27955419    DUMMY   DUMMY
29579727    DUMMY   DUMMY
27955814    DUMMY   DUMMY
27930118    DUMMY   DUMMY
27927993    DUMMY   DUMMY
27957853    DUMMY   DUMMY
27547031    DUMMY   DUMMY
29574718    DUMMY   DUMMY
27544398    DUMMY   DUMMY
1002358255  DUMMY   DUMMY
1002352871  DUMMY   DUMMY
22133310    DUMMY   DUMMY
```

And this second, is where I will get the data that I will put into the result column.

```
SOURCE

1002358255
27544381
1002352871
27955419
27927915
27927993
27955814
29579727
22133310
27957853
27547031
27930118
29587987
27544398
29574718
```

The output should be, the data of `SOURCE` column should be in `Result` column but it should match the `svc_no` column. Like this

```
svc_no      MDF     aline  Result
27544381    DUMMY   DUMMY  27544381
27927915    DUMMY   DUMMY  27927915
29587987    DUMMY   DUMMY  29587987
27955419    DUMMY   DUMMY  27955419
29579727    DUMMY   DUMMY  29579727
27955814    DUMMY   DUMMY  27955814
27930118    DUMMY   DUMMY  27930118
27927993    DUMMY   DUMMY  27927993
27957853    DUMMY   DUMMY  27957853
27547031    DUMMY   DUMMY  27547031
29574718    DUMMY   DUMMY  29574718
27544398    DUMMY   DUMMY  27544398
1002358255  DUMMY   DUMMY  1002358255
1002352871  DUMMY   DUMMY  1002352871
22133310    DUMMY   DUMMY  22133310
```

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('fortesting.xlsx')

name = df1.columns.values

df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')


list1 = df1['svc_no'].tolist()
list2 = df2['Source'].tolist()


for line in list1:
    if line in list2:
        df1['Result'] = line

df1.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

It inserts the data but it only gets one number for the entire column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('fortesting.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df1 = df1[df1['svc_no'].isin(df2['Source'])]
df1['Result'] = df1['svc_no']

df1.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('fortesting.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='svc_no', right_on='Source').rename(columns={'Source':'Result'})

df3.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: You're so amazing!! It worked for me!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @GanzoPalumi - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

`df1['Result'] = line` this is setting the whole column with a single value for every iteration in for loop, so you need to find the index and then update it like

```
for line in list1:
   if line in list2:
      idx = list1.index(line)
      df1['Result'][idx] = line
```

If you do merge in your case it wont be properly indexed also there will be two columns of Result Header

Comment: Rather not, in pandas is best avoid loops because slow.

Comment: Agreed but just pointing what was happening and how to correct it with same approach